# Insert video into HTML

Tags: html, css, video

I wanted to embed a video in HTML. I tried to do it with player script. I registered the paths and scripts, but the video is not visible on the page, although it can be found and clicking the video will open in an additional window. What's wrong?

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="intro">
      <div class="intro-wrap text-intro-wrap">
        <h1 class="title">ПОБЕждай с нами</h1>
        <p class="under-title-text">Присоединяйся к команде ПОБЕДителей.</p>
        <a href="https://xn--80aaadiigoj9aqmm.xn--p1ai/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8/?occupation=%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81" class="standard-button red-button">Хочу в команду ПОБЕДителей!</a>
      </div>
      <div class="intro-wrap">
        <a href="video/video.mp4" style="display: block; width: 300px; height: 200px;" id="player"></a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          flowplayer("player", "flowplay/flowplayer.swf");
        </script>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Did according to the instructions found.

Comment: According to the [Flowplayer docs](https://flowplayer.com/resources/demos/standard-setup?channel=stable) the first argument should be an element selector. You probably want `#player`. However, that element should be a container and not a link.

Comment: Why don't you just insert the video directly with a `<video>` element? Using a SWF player is guaranteed not to work in most browsers since the flash player has been deprecated for years now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the video tag in HTML5.

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I will work fine